# My Previous Changes are Still counted in the New PR

Tags: git, github, updates, git-rebase, git-fork

I've created a pull request to a repo. It's merged. Now, I create another PR and it includes all older commits which are in the previous PR. Is it normal or should I update something? I've already updated my both local and forked repos using `git rebase`. I think my forked repository should update itself when the PR gets merged. Right?

Comment: Try creating the PR then updating the branch - or run the command `git merge origin master` if you are on your feature branch.

Comment: There is no new branch. I've worked on master.

Comment: I run the following commands and my forked repo says your repo is 1 commit ahead of something:master which is the official repo and that's what I do want. But what exactly happened? A bit confused..!! `git rebase upstream/master` then it shows there is a conflict. Eventhough I resolve it, I ignore it using `git rebase upstream/master --skip` and then push up with `git push origin master --force` and done!!

Comment: So, it sounds like master had a commit that you did not. When you merge a PR, git usually creates a new "merge" commit that links the features to the main trunk. When I was first learning git, I found https://learngitbranching.js.org/ to be very helpful for visualizing what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I create another PR and it includes all older commits which are in the previous PR. Is it normal or should I update something?

What you should is to rebase the commits of the new PR on top of the remote updated target branch.

From:

```
         ...m--m--m  upstream/master
           /
          /
...m--m--m           previous_PR (merged)
          \
           o--o--o   new_PR
```

```bash
git fetch upstream
git rebase --onto upstream/master previous_PR new_PR
```

To:

```
                    --o'--o'--o'  new_PR (rebased)
                   /
         ...m--m--m               upstream/master
           /
          /
...m--m--m                        previous_PR (merged)
```

That way, you are ready to request a trivial PR from your branch (new_PR) to the target branch (`upstream/master`).